# Best way to use checkinstall

Tags: debian, package-management, aptitude, checkinstall

I was researching on how to properly uninstall Debian programs that I have compiled from source. One advice was to make use of `checkinstall`. But then I read on some sites that `checkinstall` doesn't take care of dependencies?

So my question is, how do I use `checkinstall` (or a better program) along with `aptitude` to get package management similar to native Debian packages?

Edit:

Basically, what is the best way to manage those programs which have to be installed from source code?

Comment: I've read some forums and the man page for `checkinstall`. It suggested I change default options by editing the /etc/checkinstallrc file, and I did so. It seems pretty safe to me to use `checkinstall` now. But I need to know anything that might go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall, the best combination would be to run `auto-apt ./configure` to take care of the dependencies, then run `make` to build and install it using `sudo checkinstall`.